# How to join socket.io to common room in server side?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0, socket.io-redis

I have next code on client:

```
Socket.notif.to(eventNameListen[i]).emit('public', { channel: eventNameListen[i] });
```

What code must be on server side, that will add current user to room `eventNameListen[i]`?

I tried:

```
socket.on('public', function (data) {
     // ???
});
```